# Return all the occurrences from a string as a list in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
exp = 'CASE WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\' ELSE  \'NO\' END'
```

I want to return the text between WHEN and THEN in all occurrences.

This is the expected output

```
['"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'',
 '"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'']
```

What I have tried is this:

```
res = re.findall(r'\s*(WHEN|When|when)+\s*(.*)\s*(THEN|Then|then)+\s*')
```

But the resulting list shows this output in my case

```
['(WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN)']
```

Comment: A simple solution, because you know it will always begin with `when` and end with `then` would to use slices to cut those out. Otherwise you can read into `lookahead` and `lookbehind`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it non-greedy with `?`:

```
re.findall("when *(.+?) *then", exp, re.I)
```

Output:

```
['"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'',
 '"Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'']
```

Comment: Thankyou for the solution.How can I get `['WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'','WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\'']` as a result using regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
exp = """CASE WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'CPU\'  THEN   \'YES\'  WHEN  "Expressions"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"=\'RAM\'  THEN   \'YES\' ELSE  \'NO\' END"""
x = re.findall("WHEN.*THEN", exp)

if x:
    print(x)
else:
    print("!!!")
```